# Dynamically add an "inline" textedit control in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I have an application that is using tinymce to display an HTML document that the user can edit/markup.  However, I need to put some control around what they can edit and often know what the intent is.  For example, the user may want to add a comment to a paragraph.  They may also highlight certain phrases in the paragraph or give the paragraph a label.  I also need to know if the user edited the original text in a paragraph.

One approach I thought of was to have the user type a shortcut (or user plugin button) that initiates the edit.  When the user types the shortcut, I want to insert a textedit control (or possibly even a dropdown with certain text phrases) inline.  When the user leaves the textedit, I get an onblur event which then updates my underlying data model.

I know I can use the windowmanager to create a popup but I want the UI to be more interactive and have the textual context around the control.

I tried to just add an input tag in my javascript that handles the shortcut but that only displayed a textbox inline that was no editable.

Below is the javascript function that executes when you click CTRL-I in the editor:

```
function insertText() {
var editor = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
if (typeof editor.selection == "undefined")
{
    return;
}

editor.insertContent('<input id="newLabel" type="textarea" name="label"

                         onblur="textEntered()"/> ');
}
```

BEFORE and AFTER Images:

[Apparently I can't post the image until I have 10 reputations.  Imagine a block of text in the before.  After ctrl-i there is a bordered text box inserted in the middle of the text block but it cannot receive keyboard focus]

Interesting though that I cut and paste the text from tinymce into Word and the edit box was editable in Word.

Below is the HTML for that text area viewed through Chrome's Inspect Element:

==================================================================

```
<span class="M-PAC_DocNo0-Q11-A11_1" style="font-size:10.0pt; 
font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:black" 
data-mce-style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; 
color: black;">I don't -- the shutdowns and the idlings that occur through the 
course of the holiday period will vary from factory to factory, as it does every year,
<input id="newLabel" name="label" type="textarea"> and that will just depend upon demand,
et cetera, for particular products that are manufactured in those factories. So some we
certainly will be idling through the course of the holidays, as we typically do. And by
the way, that's just a means by which we can most cost effectively manage when we have
open capacity, such as we do. So that's just a means by which we handle lower levels of
utilization cost effectively. So we will be doing that through the course of these 
holidays, but it will vary factory-by-factory. Okay. Tore, did you have a follow-on?</span>
```

====================================================

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Regards,

-Rob

Comment: Do you have some actual code you already tried? If so it would be better to show it and describe your actual problem with it.

Comment: Added the code that inserts the text box as well as the resulting HTML that is in the tinymce editor.  -Thanks!